# JQuery Hide & Show

Tags: jquery

When a user clicks on the submit button it sends the user to the home page (which is also the welcome page), what i have a problem with is when a user clicks on the home link, it sends them back the welcome page with the submit button. Is there a way to remove the welcome page once their name and they click to proceed?

here is the codepen of what it looks like. The example is not very good as it does not show any of the assets so that when the index page is clicked, the welcome page will show.

http://codepen.io/samyouel/pen/HqpKu

Thank you.

Comment: cookies or local storage are the usual suspects.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#submitbutton').click(function(){
     $('#yourpage').hide();
     $('#anotherpage').show();
}
```

haha :p

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a number of ways. The following might work better to keep track of it, depending on what you are trying to accomplish.

I would write the name to a cookie, on the submit "click" event, and then you can check to display the button on the page load event if the cookie has a value or not.

This is a basic example, but is to give you an idea of how to actually manage this process.

## Example:

```
var cookieValue = $.cookie("cookieName");

$(document).ready(function(){
 if(cookieValue){
    $('#yourpage').hide();
 }  
});


$('#submitbutton').click(function(){
 var txtName = $('textbox').val();

 if(cookieValue){
    $('#anotherpage').hide();         
 }else{
    $cookie("cookieName", txtName);               
    $('#yourpage').hide();
 }
}
```

I hope this helps. :)